# Zephyr RTOS dictionary logging

Tags: logging, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to get the dictionary logging example/sample in the subsys to work, however, when run it always crashes. I am using the latest Zephyr v3.5.0. Below is the screenshot of the callstack.

[image]

Below is the prj.conf.

```
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_LOG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_LOG_MODE_IMMEDIATE=y
CONFIG_LOG_BACKEND_UART_OUTPUT_DICTIONARY_HEX=y
CONFIG_LOG_BACKEND_UART_OUTPUT_DICTIONARY=y
CONFIG_LOG_BACKEND_UART=y
```

I checked the zephyr.bin and the log strings have been stripped off the binary but when run, it crashes as shown above. I'd expect this example to work out of the box, but it doesn't. Any pointers would be helpful.